# De decimal a binario en un vector

Tags: java, array, binario

Tengo este código que es para convertir un número de decimal a binario pero el problema es que me convierte el primero número pero el resto no, me tira un número enorme.

Este es el vector que estoy usando:

```
int[] array = {15, 9, 253, 50};
```

La salida debería ser: `[ 1111,  1001,  11111101,  110010 ]` pero es `[ 1111, 1111101001, 2147483647, 2147483647 ]`.

```
public int[] decimalToBinario(int[] array) {
    int resto;
    int aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        double binario = 0;
        while (array[i] != 0) {
            resto = array[i] % 2;
            binario = binario + resto * Math.pow(10, aux);
            aux++;
            array[i] = array[i] / 2;
        } // While
        aux = 0;
        array[i] = (int)binario;
    } // For

    return array;
} // Fin de método
```

Comment: No deberías resetear `aux` en algún momento tras salir del bucle `while`?

Comment: 1111
1111101001
2147483647
2147483647

Esta es la salida que obtengo si lo hago.
PD: Ya edité la pregunta @Benito-B

Comment: En ese método no hay ningún problema. Si pones un `system.out.println(array[i]);` antes del cierre del `for` veras que hace lo que quieres.

Comment: @Miguel27 si hay un problema, porque el resultado de salida no es el esperado.

Comment: De hecho, si reseteas `aux` el resultado es exactamente el esperado, Carlos...

Comment: Lo he probado porque no veía nada mal y me está dando el resultado que esperas

Comment: Como dice Miguel, todo esta bien con el método. Deberías probar con system.out.println(array[i]); para que verifiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema era que te faltaba añadir un `aux = 0;` al salir del bucle while.

Entonces qué es ese número *raro*? Buena pregunta, verdad?? Pues verás... resulta que el número `2147483647` no es tan raro en este caso...
La demostración es esta:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Imprimirá 2147483647
```

Es decir, si intentas almacenar un número *"binario"* con más de 10 dígitos, siempre te dará 2147483647.

Por lo demás, la salida de este programa es `[1111, 1001, 11111101, 110010]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {15, 9, 253, 50};
    System.out.println("Resultado: " + Arrays.toString(decimalToBinario(array)));
    // Y si lo necesitases para algo, array sigue teniendo los valores originales puesto que no se ha modificado:
    System.out.println("Array original: " + Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static int[] decimalToBinario(int[] array){
    // No es buena costumbre trabajar con los parámetros directamente, puesto que si fuese un objeto podrías
    // modificarlo sin querer. Siempre es mejor no modificar los parámetros, por si acaso!
    int[] resultado = new int[array.length];
    int resto;
    int aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        double binario = 0;
        //En vez de trabajar sobre array, trabajaremos sobre currentNumber
        int currentNumber = array[i];
        while (currentNumber != 0) {
            resto = currentNumber % 2;
            // Uso los operadores += y /= que son la forma abreviada de escribir estas operaciones
            binario += resto * Math.pow(10, aux);
            aux++;
            // Esto es el equivalente a escribir currentNumber = currentNumber / 2;
            currentNumber /= 2;
        }
        //Reseteo la variable
        aux = 0;
        resultado[i] = (int)binario;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

En los comentarios puedes encontrar comentarios explicando los cambios.

Prueba gráfica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al final almacenaste el valor es un arreglo de enteros como hiciste para que no te diera el 2147483647? y muchas gracias

Comment: Lo único que faltaba para que no diese el MAX_VALUE era resetear el `aux` para que no desbordase los enteros. Comprueba que estás ejecutando una versión del código que tenga el `aux = 0;` al salir del bucle, porque como todos dicen, lo demás lo hiciste correcto! Otra opción habría sido declarar `aux` dentro del for junto con `binario`, y ya estaría funcionando todo bien :)

Comment: muchras gracias :3

Answer (score 2):

Tu metodo funciona perfectamente, el problema se encuentra en que estas utilizando Int para almacenar el valor de los binarios, si cambias el array a long se elimina el problema, cuando el numero es demasiado grande para un Int es cuando te sale 2147483647, que es el maximo valor que almacenan los Int.